# Unison sync: recovering copy of replaced files

Tags: unison

I have configured Unison for synchronising files among servers. It takes a copy of a file from `SERVER1` and replaces or copies the file to the other servers. I just added a folder directly onto `SERVER2`, but `SERVER1` (the base server) had an older copy of that folder and its contents. After using Unison to synchronise all of my files to `SERVER2`, that folder was replaced by the older folder from `SERVER1`.

Is there any way to recover files from `SERVER2`? Does Unison itself maintain some version control or backups?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your configuration, Unison should register this as a *conflict* where you would manually need to tell it to push the files from `SERVER1` to `SERVER2`. Unison does not maintain backups by default, so unless you have enabled this, the files on `SERVER2` have been overwritten.

---

To enable backups in Unison, you need to have something like this in your Unison profile:

```
backuplocation = central
backupdir = Unison-Backups
backup = Name {.*,*}
maxbackups = 7
backupprefix = 
backupsuffix = .$VERSION
```

This will make backups of up to 7 versions of *every* file and put those backups in the `Unison-Backups` directory and will append the version number to the name of each backed-up file. See [this section](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#backups) of the Unison manual for more details.